# Expressing a variable assignment in different ways

Tags: c, variables, variable-assignment

How can a variable assignment (e.g. `x = x * 3`) be expressed in different ways?

Comment: Post what you have tried.  I am sure we can find more.

Comment: Also, if the result is the same (and for something so small, I'm guessing optimisation is not the goal), just go with what you know and what works. No point in learning 10 different ways just to avoid 1 or 2 keystrokes.

Comment: `x = x *3` doesn't make a whole lot of sense as a variable _declaration_. Or are you talking about _assignment_?

Comment: `x*=3`, `x = x + x<<1`, `x+=x<<1`

Comment: `for(i=0;i<3;i++) for(j=0;j<x;j++) x++;`

Comment: Homework, presumably.

Comment: un other example: `x *= 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
x *= 3;
```

Similarly,

```
x += 3; // it is the same as x = x + 3;
x -= 3; // it is the same as x = x - 3;
x /= 3; // it is the same as x = x/3;
```